# Mathematica Manipulate: link button with a function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

here's a simple Manipulate Menu created with Mathematica:

```
SphereSection[d_, h_] :=
    RegionPlot3D[(x^2 / d) + (y^2 / d) + (z^2 / h) <= 1, 
    {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, 0, 5},
    AxesLabel->{"Lunghezza Km" , "Larghezza  Km", "Profondità Km"},
    PlotLabel->Style[Framed["Semisfera di riferimento"],25]]

 Manipulate[
  {diameter,highness,estimatedPorosity,waterSaturation,netOnGross,bg},             
  {diameter, 0, 200},{highness,0,200},{estimatedPorosity,0,100},
  {waterSaturation, 0, 100}, {netOnGross, 0, 100}, {bg, 0, 1},
   Button["GO", SphereSection[diameter, highness]]]
```

When I set the diameter and highness with the graphic menu, I expect that the function SphereSection is called after I've pressed the button but nothing happens...instead if I call directly

```
SphereSection[2,3]
```

then it draws the section of the sphere correctly...how can I link the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
   Manipulate[SphereSection[diameter, highness],
       {{diameter, 100}, 0, 200},
       {{highness, 100}, 0, 200},
       {estimatedPorosity, 0, 100},
       {waterSaturation, 0, 100},
       {netOnGross, 0, 100},
       {bg, 0, 1}]
```

If you actually want the result held until you press a button that's a little harder.
This is quick and dirty approach. Note you need to "use" the dummy variable `update` in order for it to wrok as a TrackedSymbol

```
 Manipulate[update; SphereSection[diameter, highness],
    {{diameter, 100}, 0, 200},
    {{highness, 100}, 0, 200},
    {estimatedPorosity, 0, 100},
    {waterSaturation, 0, 100},
    {netOnGross, 0, 100},
    {bg, 0, 1}, {update, {True, False}}, TrackedSymbols :> {update}]
```